# Share different values on same tooltip in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

Is it possible to show a tooltip with all the same x values of a composite chart? I mean, if we have a JSON with 
`{"date":"1/18/2001", "Open":54.77, "High":56.19, "Low": 52.63, "Close": 55.50}`

show something like this:

[image: Example tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

If the same data is used for all the parts of the composite chart (i.e. same group but different `valueAccessors`, you can use [compositeChart.shareTitle(true)](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.compositeChart.html#shareTitle__anchor) to pass the same title accessor down to all the child charts.

This works well if you're reducing multiple values into an object like your example.

Then you just need to set [baseMixin.title](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#title) to display all the parts with newlines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gordon, I have 4 series, each serie is a different group.

Comment: Hmm this may still be possible but it will require a little hacking. Maybe not too bad as long as the groups have the same set of keys (so that we can "join" by index instead of key).